# python 2.7 multithreads hang in print

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, deadlock, freeze

my python software deadlocks interminttently (probably due to some race condition)

inside one of the running thread, it runs

```
while True:
   msg = printQ.get()
   print msg
   sys.stdout.flush()
```

while debugging, i saw one of my thread held up at 
sys.stdout.flush(). If i remove flush line, the thread hangs at print.
This is the only thread which prints to stdout

If i disable this thread, my software doesnt deadlock

are there any known issues with flushing stdout in multithreaded env?

these are tracing of running threads at the time when the software deadlocked. Anything jumps out to you guys? to me, it looks like a couple of sleep and waiting for item in the queue. only thing that's odd to me is sys.stdout.flush()

```
# ThreadID: 139736001795840
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 726, in worker
  jobref = Host.r.blpop(Dispatch.rkey_completeQ, timeout=1)
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1090, in blpop
  return self.execute_command('BLPOP', *keys)
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 529, in execute_command
  return self.parse_response(connection, command_name, **options)
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 541, in parse_response
  response = connection.read_response()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 545, in read_response
  response = self._parser.read_response()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 213, in read_response
  response = self._buffer.readline()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 151, in readline
  self._read_from_socket()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 109, in _read_from_socket
  data = self._sock.recv(socket_read_size)

# ThreadID: 139736012285696
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 605, in worker
  job = Factory.dispQ.get()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  self.not_empty.wait()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340, in wait
  waiter.acquire()

# ThreadID: 139736022775552
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 605, in worker
  job = Factory.dispQ.get()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  self.not_empty.wait()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340, in wait
  waiter.acquire()

# ThreadID: 139737333483264
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 236, in worker
  (job, msg, to_debug) = Factory.logQ.get()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  self.not_empty.wait()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340, in wait
  waiter.acquire()

# ThreadID: 139736461068032
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 605, in worker
  job = Factory.dispQ.get()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  self.not_empty.wait()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340, in wait
  waiter.acquire()

# ThreadID: 139736492537600
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 470, in worker
  job = Factory.rdyQ.get()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  self.not_empty.wait()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340, in wait
  waiter.acquire()

# ThreadID: 139737322993408
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 313, in worker
  sys.stdout.flush()

# ThreadID: 139736909850368
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 470, in worker
  job = Factory.rdyQ.get()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  self.not_empty.wait()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340, in wait
  waiter.acquire()

# ThreadID: 139736920340224
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 470, in worker
  job = Factory.rdyQ.get()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  self.not_empty.wait()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340, in wait
  waiter.acquire()

# ThreadID: 139737354462976
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 350, in worker
  item = Factory.streamQ.get()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  self.not_empty.wait()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340, in wait
  waiter.acquire()

# ThreadID: 139736930830080
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 470, in worker
  job = Factory.rdyQ.get()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  self.not_empty.wait()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340, in wait
  waiter.acquire()

# ThreadID: 139736471557888
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 470, in worker
  job = Factory.rdyQ.get()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  self.not_empty.wait()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340, in wait
  waiter.acquire()

# ThreadID: 139736951809792
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 470, in worker
  job = Factory.rdyQ.get()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  self.not_empty.wait()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340, in wait
  waiter.acquire()

# ThreadID: 139736962299648
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 470, in worker
  job = Factory.rdyQ.get()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  self.not_empty.wait()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340, in wait
  waiter.acquire()

# ThreadID: 139737474270976
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Status_thread.py", line 131, in run
  request = self._queue.get(timeout=1) # blocking get with a timeout of 1 second
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 177, in get
  self.not_empty.wait(remaining)
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 359, in wait
  _sleep(delay)

# ThreadID: 139736450578176
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 605, in worker
  job = Factory.dispQ.get()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  self.not_empty.wait()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340, in wait
  waiter.acquire()

# ThreadID: 139737364952832
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Stack_Tracer.py", line 56, in run
  self.stacktraces()
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Stack_Tracer.py", line 70, in stacktraces
  fout.write(stacktraces())
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Stack_Tracer.py", line 22, in stacktraces
  for filename, lineno, name, line in traceback.extract_stack(stack):

# ThreadID: 139737343973120
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 416, in worker
  time.sleep(1)

# ThreadID: 139736440088320
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 605, in worker
  job = Factory.dispQ.get()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  self.not_empty.wait()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340, in wait
  waiter.acquire()

# ThreadID: 139736482047744
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 470, in worker
  job = Factory.rdyQ.get()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  self.not_empty.wait()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340, in wait
  waiter.acquire()

# ThreadID: 139737312503552
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 470, in worker
  job = Factory.rdyQ.get()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  self.not_empty.wait()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340, in wait
  waiter.acquire()

# ThreadID: 139737628997376
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Br.py", line 86, in <module>
  Command.main()
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Command.py", line 149, in main
  com.run(args)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Btool.py", line 181, in run
  self.make_locked(args)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Btool.py", line 227, in make_locked
  Dispatch.run_jobs()
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch.py", line 732, in run_jobs
  # we got any hung jobs??
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch.py", line 332, in check_for_hung_jobs
  really_running = job.log_check()
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Job.py", line 391, in log_check
  if Checkproc.check_remote_process(Options.options.rsh_cmd, lock.hostname, lock.pid, 20):
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Checkproc.py", line 92, in check_remote_process
  time.sleep(1)

# ThreadID: 139736941319936
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/u/eugenep/bedrock/source/br-new-release/lib/btool/Dispatch_Factory.py", line 470, in worker
  job = Factory.rdyQ.get()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  self.not_empty.wait()
File: "/usr/software/rats/bedrock/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 340, in wait
  waiter.acquire()
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK sys.stdout is not really thread-safe, but without any code, it's actually impossible to say. For debugging purposes you could try to lock `sys.stdout.flush`, e.g.:

```
orig_flush = sys.stdout.flush
flush_lock = threading.Lock()

def myflush():  
    with flush_lock:
        orig_flush()

sys.stdout.flush = myflush

# ... eventually:
sys.stdout.flush = orig_flush
```